# NPM install java Issue on windows 10

Tags: java, node.js, npm, sails.js, loopback

I am using cmd as administrator to install java using npm install java and i am getting an error. All environment variables are set as well. Any help will be very applicable. Thanks in advance..

`gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error:`gyp`failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js
:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\MyName\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gy
p\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\WINDOWS\system32
gyp ERR! node -v v8.1.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this procedure

```
rm -rf ~/.node-gyp/
rm -r node_modules/.bin/;
rm -r build/
npm install bcrypt
```

and set

```
npm config set msvs_version 2013 --global
```

Comment: Thanks for your Suggestion